# UIimageView problem

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

Hi Friends'
i am new to using cocos2d application , and i want to build a grid of images using a single square image.
i make that in UIImageview now i want to ask that how can i add that...
if i use [self addchild: (CCNode)square] it show error .

thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Hi friend :) What's the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not use UIImageView's with cocos2d.

Try this.

```
CCSprite *square = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"yourimage.png"];
[self addChild:square];
```

I'm presuming self is a CCLayer.

Sounds like you need up on some basics.

There are some good beginner tutorials here.

http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/

Comment: ohoo friend i already did that . I make a cube class:uiimageView(subclass) ...ok now i add images in uiimageview and try to show but it not help ..when i try to add it show error

Comment: why are you using UIImageView?